# Iterative Mean of Means Infinite Loop for calculating H-t Index

Tags: r, loop, digital-image-processing, iteration

I'm trying to create a function that will calculate an [Ht-Index for Quantifying the Fractal or Scaling Structure of Geographic Features](http://arrow.dit.ie/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1072&context=dmcart) (but am new to R)

which basically just finds nested means of continuous data (raster in this case) and separates them into 2 groups: heads and tails (values above and below the means). The Ht-Index is the number of times (-1) the 'heads' group can be subdivided without being greater than some threshold (e.g., 45%) of the distribution of both groups. I'm not sure how to efficiently do this in R but here is my failed attempt which creates an infinite loop iterating over the same input.

---

```
require(raster)

foo <- raster('/foobar.img')

hindex <- function(x){
iCounter <-0
repeat{
    head <- x[x>mean(x)]  # need to replace x each iteration for head and tail
    tail <- x[x<mean(x)]  
    headpct <- length(head)/sum(length(head),length(tail)) 
    if (headpct >.45) break # If head is > 45% of values stop
        else
            if (length(head)== 1) break # if head is only one value stop
    x <- head
    iCounter <- iCounter+1
    }
return(iCounter-1) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without looking too deeply into what you are doing, returning the number of iterations is fairly straight forward.  I have now made it so that infinite loops don't happen and made the threshold one of the function parameters.

```
hindex <- function(x, threshold){
iCounter <- 0 # Make counter 0
repeat{
    head <- x[x>mean(x)]
    tail <- x[x<mean(x)]
    headpct <- length(head)/sum(length(head),length(tail))
    if (headpct > threshold) break # If head is > threshold of values stop
        else
            if (length(head)== 1) break # if head is only one value stop
    x <- head # reset X
    iCounter <- iCounter + 1 # Only increment if break doesn't occur
    }
return(iCounter) 
}
```